# Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/jsx"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, server, mime-types

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/jsx". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

When i deployed it on aws amplify i am getting this error

Comment: hey you
I encounter the same issue when deploying react + vite project on amplify..
did you solve this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75117057 this solve my issue